# ruby on rails 3, active record, how to address data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have active record model that has one to many relationship.
This is how it looks like:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :001 > @ukuizvj=Izvjestaj.new(:mjesec=>8, :godina=>2011,:djelatnik_id=>2)
 => #<Izvjestaj id: nil, godina: 2011, mjesec: 8, djelatnik_id: 2, brojsati: nil, visak: nil, manjak: nil, nr: nil, rp: nil, komb: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>


ruby-1.9.2-p290 :002 > @ukuizvj.izvjtipd
 => []


ruby-1.9.2-p290 :003 > ntiprada=Izvjtipd.new(:tipneradni_id=>1, :vrijednost=>1)
 => #<Izvjtipd id: nil, izvjestaj_id: nil, tipneradni_id: 1, vrijednost: 1, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>



ruby-1.9.2-p290 :004 > @ukuizvj.izvjtipd << ntiprada
 => [#<Izvjtipd id: nil, izvjestaj_id: nil, tipneradni_id: 1, vrijednost: 1, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>]



ruby-1.9.2-p290 :005 > @ukuizvj.izvjtipd
 => [#<Izvjtipd id: nil, izvjestaj_id: nil, tipneradni_id: 1, vrijednost: 1, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>]
```

So, How can I address this value of @ukuizvj.izvjtipd? Problem is that 
@ukuizvj.izvjtipd.find_by_tipneradni_id(1).vrijednost
or 
@ukuizvj.izvjtipd.where(:tipneradni_id=>1).vrijednost
dont work until I make @ukuizvj.save

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use build:

```
 @ukuizvj.izvjtipd.build(:tipneradni_id=>1, :vrijednost=>1)
```

Comment: ok, but how can address vrijenost where :tipneradni_id=>1 ? thank you